# No Java folder available in OpenCV folder structure

Tags: java, opencv, ocr

I wanted to use Open CV in my project and followed below installation process:

http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-x-under-macos

I was not able to get Java folder in the installed directory. As I was getting below error on my Java code:

"NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME cannot be resolved"

I tried few things till now -

1. I did "brew edit opencv" and changed "-DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF" to "ON" and did "brew reinstall opencv --with-java"
2. I tried adding external jar and tried changing the native library location but no help as there is no java folder available in opencv directory

I am not getting help from any source.

Comment: You need OpenCV in Android project or some Java Application ?

Comment: I need it in Java project as I am doing some preprocessing over the image.

Comment: Check the installation guide to be one to one to your platform. May be a difference in the Java wrapper causes it not to be able to resolve NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

For build OpenCV with java libraries you should make project with parametr

```
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

After configure project you should see java in OpenCV modules

```
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built: ... java ...
```

And

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.1)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java/include /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
```

If you build project with this parametrs, but didn't see **java** in OpenCV modules then try set JAVA_HOME environment
For linux

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path_to_jdk>
```

For windows

```
set JAVA_HOME=<path_to_jdk>
```

I builded OpenCV project with command below:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_JAVA=ON
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
    -D WITH_IPP=ON 
    -D WITH_TBB=ON
    -D IPP_H_PATH=/opt/intel/ipp/include/ ..
```

Parametrs WITH_IPP and WITH_TBB provide multithreading.

After make install phase you can see jar library in ../bin and /usr/[local/]share/OpenCV

Related resources:

1) [Oficial site](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)

2) [Man for Linux install process](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-7)

3) [Add OpenCV to Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288646/how-to-use-java-opencv)

Comment: I am trying to install openCV with java on MACOS exactly following the procedure but everytime there is no JAVA folder! Please help

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't know how to save the change of arg

```
DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF
```

to

```
DBUILD_opencv_java=ON
```

Such file exist on :

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/opencv.rb
```

So open it with any text editor and save it easily.